# Encrypted (luks) + LVM Ubuntu installation where /home is encrypted as well (ecryptfs): How to make a new partition for /home?

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, directory, home

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04, encrypted and with LVM. I also chose the option to encrypt `/home` (which encrypts the directory with eCryptfs).

The default settings make an unencrypted `/boot` and an encrypted partition with LVM which contains swap and `/`.

I want to resize `/` after installation and make a new partition for /home (which should still be using ecryptfs).

To do that, I downloaded `system-config-lvm`, resized root and made a new partition which mounts to `/home`.

However after a reboot, the `/home` directory only contains lost+found and the user and eCryptfs are gone.

How can I separate `/home` from `/` properly?

P.S. If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is that `/` is not split to save whatever `/home` contains, but that newly created `/home` partition (which is from the free space of `/`) is being mounted over whatever initially was at `/home`, if that makes any sense.

**Update**

I've solved it by manually doing luksFormat and lvcreate etc and having the UUID of the extended partition (the one without boot that'll be encrypted) to crypttab and update initramfs. The process is the exact same thing as if you were using Slackware or something similar.

The only unusual thing was that the bootloader should not be installed on /dev/sda or /dev/mapper/ etc. It should be installed on the /dev/sda1 (i.e. the boot partition).

As for ecryptfs, after installation, install "ecryptfs-utils" and make a new user and put it in sudoers file. Log out and login to that new user and do "sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u USER".